# Are questions asking definitions about tech stuff on-topic?

Tags: support, on-topic-off-topic

I want to ask what the difference is in common English usage between two particular words having to do with Internet browsers.

Comment: Depends on just how narrow/niche the specific question is. But demonstrating, in the body of the question,  a healthy amount of prior independent research can go a very long way towards making almost any question of meaning on topic. You might also want to briefly describe your reasons or motivation for asking in the first place.

Comment: Without knowing the words in question, that is probably a reasonable use of ELU. But note that in a recent question http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/261759/what-do-source-and-sink-mean, the OP could have helped themselves out by checking a dictionary first (and not stopping at the first definition or by thinking a little metaphorically). Like @DanBron said, showing that you've done _some_ research makes answerers feel like they're helping out rather than just doing someone else's work for them.

Comment: @DanBron: I didn't want to ask the question in here because I was concerned someone would try to answer it. But this isn't the place to answer my question; it's the place to answer whether or not I can ask the question.

Comment: @Mitch: I did plenty of research; I'm not a beginner in this, you know. δ_δ

Comment: @Mitch: Ignore that last statement. I was a bit on edge at the time I wrote it and I apologise. How, after all, could you know whether I'm a beginner or not in what way to what degree? My apologies.

Comment: @SarahofGaia Yes, I wasn't suggesting you ask your question here on Meta. You're right that Main is the place for it. I was just offering suggestions on what to include in the question which mitigate risk. Questions which border on specific industry jargon have a relatively higher risk of closure (as you're aware, hence this Meta-question you asked); I was just offering strategies which have proven to mitigate that risk.

Comment: @DanBron: Definitely true. I thank you for that. I'm sorry if I was being rude myself.

Comment: @SarahofGaia ha ha, I didn't realize that was something that needed an apology. Now that I do, how dare you! Now that you've apologized, I'm sorry myself if I spoke in a rude way.

Comment: Also, tech stuff often can be off-topic because it is language of a very particular culture that people here may not be familiar with. Internet browsers...probably no problem at all.

Comment: @Mitch: Lol, okay, apology accepted. xP

Also, I thought of a good compromise that would answer both questions I have. On Super User, I would ask what the technical definitions of the words I want to ask about are; then, on this site, I would ask whether the *popular* definitions are aligned with the technical definitions, and if not then what are they. ^_^

Comment: Also, is it *Super User* or *SuperUser*? I've seen it both ways... :/

Comment: @SarahofGaia what's the context? I'd probably write "superuser". It started off as 'super user' (two words) then 'super-user' and quickly moved on to 'superuser'. No capitalization.

Comment: @Mitch: The context is Internet browsers.

Comment: @Mitch: And okay. I see people writing it as "SuperUser" in informal contexts, like in threads and stuff, but it's also often written as "Super User" in more formal contexts, such as at the bottom of this page, for instance.

Comment: @SarahofGaia Oh... do you mean not the informal term but the label for the SO site? For such things, anything goes, and there are no rules other than 'this is the way it is'. For the SO site, it looks like it is two capitalized words 'Super' and 'User'. Is that what you're asking about then? I wouldn't call this technical usage but rather ... title or commercial usage?

Comment: I mean all usage—that is, both colloquial, technical, and commercial.

Comment: @Mitch: Are you sure about that? The earliest instance of ["unix superuser"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unix+superuser%22&biw=1202&bih=795&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1985&tbm=bks) I can find is 1983. I find a few *later* instances of the two-word (and hyphenated) versions, but I think they're just "mistakes" anyway.

Comment: I mean colloquial, technical, and commercial usage of the name for the StackExchange website. Lol.

Comment: See, there we go again: *StackExchange* or *Stack Exchange*? *StackOverflow* or *Stack Overflow*? *SoftwareRecommendations* or *Software Recommendations*? xD

Comment: I see a lot of StackExchange/Stack Exchange websites being spelled with and without the space. Haha.